# Is there a way not to download the entire CKAN data package with ckanr in R?

Tags: r, ckan

I am unfamiliar with the CKAN and I am struggling to get data from a CKAN data API loaded into R using the `ckanr` package from R Cran repository. Server wise the download is limited to 100,000 entries, so trying downloading the entire 420,000 entries will not return more than the first 100,000 entries. The dataset provides an updated history for the CO2 emission from electricity consumed in Denmark measured in g/kWh in time intervals of 5 minutes.

Using the code snippet below, I am able to download the 100,000 first entries. I am interested in an interval of approximately 20,000 values, in a specific date range. The data could be downloaded manually via an webinterface, but as I will have to update the data regularly and manually download multiple CSV files each time, a data API download would be much preferred.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**The webinterface:**
https://www.energidataservice.dk/dataset/co2emis/resource_extract/b5a8e0bc-44af-49d7-bb57-8f968f96932d

**The Data API can be accessed via the following actions of the CKAN action API.**

Query:  https://api.energidataservice.dk/datastore_search

Query (via SQL): https://api.energidataservice.dk/datastore_search_sqlhttps://api.energidataservice.dk/datastore_search

```
require(ckanr)
start_date <- min(opladning$start)
end_date <- max(opladning$slut)

ckanr_setup(url = "https://energidataservice.dk")
pkco2emis <- package_show("6e05f3b6-fcd7-4b40-8100-4416b9803881", as 
= "table")


temp <- tempfile(fileext=".csv")
download.file(pkco2emis$resources$url, temp)
co2emission <- read.csv(temp)
```

Comment: `ckanr` maintainer here. I am confused about what exactly you want. can you clarify

Comment: I was looking for a way to filter the package content, before downloading it. I not sure it is possible with CKAN.

Comment: I ended up parsing a SQL query instead without using the ```ckanr``` package, and returning the results with the ```fromJson``` function in the ```jsonlite```package.

Answer (score 0):

By parsing an URL SQL query to the REST API via the *ds_search_sql* function from the `ckanr` package, I was able to extract the data from the API.

```
#end_date and start_date represent interval.
library(ckanr)
library(lubridate)

start_date <- as.POSIXct("2019-01-01 00:00:00")
end_date <- as.POSIXct("2019-03-01 00:00:00")



url_base <- 'https://api.energidataservice.dk/datastore_search_sql?sql='
query_co2 <- 'SELECT "Minutes5DK", "CO2Emission" from "b5a8e0bc-44af-49d7-bb57-8f968f96932d" WHERE "Minutes5UTC" > timestamp\''
query_date_start <- format(with_tz(start_date, "UTC"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%S")
query_date_end <- format(with_tz(end_date, "UTC"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%S")
query_co2 <- paste0(query_co2,query_date_start,
                '\' AND \"Minutes5UTC\" < timestamp\'',
                query_date_end,
                '\' AND \"PriceArea\" = \'DK1\'')




co2emission <- ds_search_sql(query_co2, 
                         url = url_base, 
                         as = "table")$records
```

Comment: Did you see the `ds_search_sql` function in `ckanr`? That should probably do what you need. Let me know if it works or doesn't work

Comment: Thank you @sckott I edited my answer using ```ds_search_sql```instead.

Comment: Is this reproducible, trying to run the answer and getting: 

`Error in ds_search_sql(query_co2, url = url_base, as = "table")...`

Comment: I have corrected the code, so that it is now reproducible. In addition to the `ckanr` package the above code requires the `lubridate` package.